# Query String AND Master Page

Tags: asp.net

I have one Master Page named MyMaster.Master and two other Pages Login.aspx (Without Master Page) and StudentRegistration.aspx (With Master Page). After Successful Login, I m redirecting to StudentRegistration.aspx using Query String

Response.Redirect("StudentRegistration.aspx?Name="+ Name);

How to display that Name (in Query String) in side bar of MyMaster.Master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access below in your master page,

```
Request.QueryString("Name")
```

Comment: Be sure to validate that before display or you are open to cross site scriptiing